# Flowplayer (new) HTML5 - Autoplay Problems

Tags: jquery, html5-video, flowplayer

I am trying to get the new Flowplayer 5.1.1 that performs as HTML5 to Autostart.

Tried many things but can't get it to work.

Here's how I initialize the actual video:

```
<div class="flowplayer minimalist"><video src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/white/470x250.mp4"></video></div>
```

This works in general and the video is shown.

How can I get this video to autoplay?

Any ideas?

Thank you all!

Comment: Add autoplay to the video tag.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot! That worked. Very convenient, a shame it was so difficult to find on Flowplayer's website etc.

Comment: Jay, you should add this as an answer.